Holes drilled too big for anchor
I am trying to put on roller blind and I recently posted here about screw and anchor size bit drill but I did the experiment prior to asking question, but now as you can see the top (marked red) hole seems empty but it took 3 anchor inside!

So my first question is how to fill/closes these holes? To drill again:
How to find right bit size for anchor? In a haystack of bits?



P.S - How do I know what kind of wall is it? It look like cardboard material.

Before we go much further, what are you trying to hang/mount?  Drywall anchors should only be used for light weight stuff.  For heavy weight and/or expensive stuff you really want to screw into studs.  Curtains/drapes are the same since they can be pulled on.

For anchors, place anchor on flat surface.  Hold drill bit over it.  When drill bit does not hide the outside of the anchor, that is the right size.

@crip659 I am trying to mount roller blinds. I will add that to question as well. thanks

I would like to screw into studs.  There should be one or two just to the left of the red/blue holes.  If no studs(unlikely) then use toggle anchors.  They have wings that spring out and hold much better than that little anchor.

Before you throw more anchors into the wall, get some proper drywall anchors. The ones you're using work much betting in solid masonry than they do in hollow drywall.

@brhans I was googling them and it’s in mm like 52mm etc. what should I be looking for?

Here's an example of what we call a drywall anchor here in the US: https://www.stainlessstairparts.com/cdn/shop/products/stainless-steel-wall-anchorage_1024x.jpg  You're using mm, so likely not in the US, so YMMV what's available in your area.
